# Debugging template deduction failure

Tags: c++, templates

Why doesn't the following work:

```
std::string fn(int i)
{
        sleep(i); // number of seconds to sleep for
        std::cout << "Exiting after pausing " << i << " seconds\n";
        return std::to_string(i+1);
}

template<typename T, typename U>
int simult( std::function<T(U)> f, std::vector<U> args)
{
        return 666;
}


int main()
{

        std::vector<int> args { 6, 5, 7 };        
        int r = simult(fn, args);
}
```

Function simult obviously isn't complete: I'm just trying to get something to compile at this stage. The idea is that you supply a function and a list of args, and simult will apply the args piecewise to f using threaded calls.

At this stage, I'm just trying to figure out the compilation problem.

```
simult.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
simult.cc:43:25: error: no matching function for call to ‘simult(std::__cxx11::string (&)(int), std::vector<int>&)’
  int r = simult(fn, args);
                         ^
simult.cc:23:5: note: candidate: template<class T, class U> int simult(std::function<T(U)>, std::vector<U>)
 int simult( std::function<T(U)> f, std::vector<U> args)
     ^~~~~~
simult.cc:23:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
simult.cc:43:25: note:   mismatched types ‘std::function<T(U)>’ and ‘std::__cxx11::string (*)(int) {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> (*)(int)}’
  int r = simult(fn, args);
                         ^
```

Comment: you're not really giving the compiler any help! Firstly passing in a function pointer, which it then has to assign to a `std::function<>` for which it has to determine the template type?

Comment: Ha. I always use 666 as a test integer. On these grounds I like this, plus one.

Comment: @Bathsheba actually in 80% of the sacred texts the number is 616 and not 666 so you have nothing to worry about...

Comment: I personally prefer 42.

Comment: @SergeyA I also use 42 sometimes. Actually, I use 666 for things that are incomplete, and need me to sort out, and 42 in examples which are considered complete.

Answer (score 1):

Template deductions do not trigger implicit conversion. Although function (pointer) type is **convertible** to `std::function`, this conversion is never part of template substitution.

You will have to construct `std::function` and pass it to the `simlut`:

```
int r = simult(std::function<std::string (int)>(fn), args);
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work due to the fact that user defined conversions are not considered in template argument deduction.

You could either help the compiler by explicitly providing the template arguments, and call `simult` as:

```
int r = simult<std::string, int>(fn, args);
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/35d09f36235bfafe)

Or you could make it work out with use of `decltype` as follows:

```
std::string fn(int i) {
  return std::to_string(i + 1);
}

template<typename T, typename U>
int simult_impl(std::function<T(U)> f, std::vector<U> const &args) {
  return 666;
}

template<typename F, typename U>
int simult(F f, std::vector<U> const &args) {
  return simult_impl<decltype(f(args[0])), U>(f, args);
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f73045bf2cf96a96)

Edit:

If you want to return a `std::vector<T>` provided that your compiler supports C++14 you can change as follows:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
std::vector<T> simult_impl(std::function<T(U)> f, std::vector<U> const &args) {
  return std::vector<T>(10, T{"666"});
}

template<typename F, typename U>
auto simult(F f, std::vector<U> const &args) {
  return simult_impl<decltype(f(args[0])), U>(f, args);
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/020c1e50c32b9446)

Comment: I particularly like your second part, except that ultimately I don't want to return an `int`, I want to return `std::vector<T>`, which is dependent on how the passed function was defined.

Comment: Many thanks. I will check it out. Yes, I do have a C++14 compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Using the suggestion from @SergeyA, I was able to come up with working code, now as a full example:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

#include <unistd.h> // for sleep. Not needed generally

// declare a function that does what you want
std::string fn(int i)
{
        sleep(i); // number of seconds to sleep for
        std::cout << "Exiting after pausing " << i << " seconds\n";
        return std::to_string(i+1);
}



template<typename T, typename U>
std::vector<T> simult(std::function<T(U)> func, std::vector<U> const &args)
{
        std::vector<std::future<T>> fs;
        for(auto& a:args) fs.push_back(std::async(func, a));

        std::vector<T> results;
        for(auto &f:fs) results.push_back(f.get());
        return results;
}



int main()
{
        std::vector<int> args { 6, 5, 7 };
        std::vector<std::string> results = simult(std::function<std::string (int)>(fn), args);
        std::cout << "Results are:\n";
        for(auto&r:results) std::cout << r << "\n"; //results are returned in correct order
        return 0;
}
```

Compile:

```
g++ simult.cc -o simult -lpthread
```

Run:

```
time -p simult
Exiting after pausing 5 seconds
Exiting after pausing 6 seconds
Exiting after pausing 7 seconds
Results are:
7
6
8
real 7.00
user 0.00
sys 0.00
```

I'm still a bit puzzled as to why C++ can't deduce the type of the function by itself, but I guess the important thing is that it works. It just seems that the caller is unnecessarily verbose to me.

**Edit**: In function `simult()`, replaced instances of `std::string` with `T`.

**Edit**: changed `std::vector<U> args` to `std::vector<U> const &args`